# Javascript Regex Problem with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this home-made function to validate text fields, but for some reason, it doesn't "accept" spaces. I find that weird, since I have \s in my class...

```
function validateText(controlid, minlength, maxlength, required) {
    var control = document.getElementById(controlid);
    if (!required && control.value.length == 0) control.style.backgroundColor = "White";
    else {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\.\s_,:/-]{" + minlength + "," + maxlength + "}$", "g");
        if (!regex.test(control.value))
            control.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDDDD";
        else
            control.style.backgroundColor = "White";
    }
}
```

Can you tell me why entering a space turns the textbox red? Thanks :)

Comment: What is the minlength and maxlength values in that case

Comment: @Jesper - I made a demo, and working fine. hope some help ~ [http://jsfiddle.net/5ryx8/](http://jsfiddle.net/5ryx8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because you're trying to put `\s` in a class. Inside a class (eg, []) `\s` is simple a badly-escaped "s". Either use a literal space, or do `^([...]|\s){`.

Comment: Yes, if you replace the \s with a space, it works.  You can see it work here in the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ne6zC/.